# Inconsistency with recommendations for resistors for LEDs

Tags: led

I'm so confused. I've got a Pi operating obviously at 3.3v and I know I need to use resistors to avoid damage.

However I *cannot* find any consistency in the tutorials for what value to use. I've seen anything and everything between "you don't need to use one at 3.3v" to 82ohm, to 100ohm, to 500ohm, up to 1K.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this please!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please clarify if [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55120/19949) does or does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

**You ALWAYS need a resistor with a LED**.  If you don't limit the current they will burn out in an instant.

The resistor to be used will vary because LEDs vary.

Some need very little current to be bright.

Different colours of LED have different forward voltages and need different resistors to get the same relative brightness.

Comment: yes I know. So take this example. Red 5mm LED 80mcd 2Vf lfmax=30mA. I reckon I nee an 36ohm resistor or closest to it, right?

Comment: Ummm... no, that's not true. You do need to **limit the current** through the LED, but the  [***constant current diode***](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=constant+current+diode&ia=web) will also do that - as a bonus, they supply (almost) the same current over a wide range of voltages. And some LEDs have *in-built* current-limiting resistors for a specific voltage.

Comment: Who are you talking to when you say "no that's not true", me or @joan ? Thank you

Comment: @dannee He's referring to me.  He thinks I should have put current limiter instead of or in addition to you always need a resistor.

Comment: thanks @joan! :-D god EE is a minefield... I don't think I have the head for it but I do love to tinker.

Answer (score 0):

No one can comment on the inconsistencies you may find in in the (unreferenced) tutorials.
Also no one can tell without a specification of the LED.

LEDS **ALWAYS** require some form of current limitation; this usually takes the form of a resistor, but active constant current circuits or switching regulators can be used.
The resistor or constant current circuit can be builtin to the LED - this is quite common for high intensity LED, but these are generally unsuitable for the Pi.

There is no recommended value, but it is simple to calculate.
**R = (3.3V - V<sub>led</sub>) / I<sub>led</sub>**

The Pi GPIO can safely supply a maximum of 16mA so **anything over 120Ω** *(3.3V - 1.3V)/0.016* will be safe.

The Activity LED on the Pi uses a 1kΩ resistor.

LED voltage (**V<sub>led</sub>**) varies from 1.3V to 3.6V (depending on colour) and current (**I<sub>led</sub>**) on desired brightness.